# ATI/AMD Radeon driver through jockey results in error

Tags: radeon, ati

I am not trying to waste the resource of askubuntu. I've tried a lot of methods shown online, but i still can't this done.

I 'have installed ubuntu 11.10 in my laptop. I have both Intel 3000 HD graphic and AMD Radeon 6470 HD. Of course I want to make use of my AMD vga.

I've tried:

1. Download the driver through additial drivers and restart the machine.
   Result: 
         i. Before driver installation, I got unity 3D, after that, it become 2D. I log 
            off, and choose Ubuntu 3D, still I can't get the 3D effect 
        ii. I went to system info, graphic, driver unknown, experience standard
       iii. I opened amd catalyst, error message something like driver is not installed 
            appropietary
2. Download latest amd catalyst 11.11 for linux 64 bits, after follow the online steps,
   purge the original driver, and install the .run installer and so on.
   Result: 
         I restart PC, and 1 process fail to start up, and i can't get into Ubuntu 
         Desktop. Have to re-install ubuntu.

Thanks for helping me and sorry for my broken english. Appreciate if someone helps edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow [this](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/install-ati-official-drivers-in-ubuntu/) 
steps when installing ATI drivers.

Comment: I followed similar steps as the guide, and when I tried to restart my PC, I could not get into the Desktop, and I format my PC. Any way I can backup my system state, and if I fail again, I can recover to original state before installing the driver?

Comment: You can recover using Deja Dup. It uses duplicity. Make sure you uninstall the video driver before any new driver installation.